# How to reverse sort a map and send it to model in go lang

Tags: sorting, dictionary, go, model, reverse

I want to send a reverse order of a list of books that are stored in a map and send this to a model instead of the map in its current order.

I need to display a list in reverse order of date entered which is pubDate so that the webpage (model) displays the most recently added books instead of the books added first.

I have tried many various sort methods listed but I do not know how I would send this to the model.  For example, I tried 
import "sort"

```
var m map[int]string
var keys []int
for k := range m {
    keys = append(keys, k)
}
sort.Ints(keys)
for _, k := range keys {
    fmt.Println("Key:", k, "Value:", m[k])
}
```

I also tried
sort.Slice(ad, func(i, j int) bool {

```
    return ad[i].date.Before(ad[j].date)})
```

there are many others but I can not seem to get any working.

```
type Book struct {
    ID     int64  `json:"id"`
    Title  string `json:"title"`
    Author string `json:"author"`
    pubDate time.Time `json:"pubDate"`
}

var bookModels = map[string]*Book{}

s := res.NewService("library")

    // Add handlers for "library.book.$id" models
    s.Handle(
        "book.$id",
        res.Access(res.AccessGranted),
        res.GetModel(getBookHandler),
        res.Set(setBookHandler),
    )

    // Add handlers for "library.books" collection
    s.Handle(
        "books",
        res.Access(res.AccessGranted),
        res.GetCollection(getBooksHandler),
        res.New(newBookHandler),
        res.Call("delete", deleteBookHandler),
    )

func getBookHandler(r res.ModelRequest) {

    book := bookModels[r.ResourceName()]
    if book == nil {
        r.NotFound()
        return
    }
    r.Model(book)
}
```

Mainly I get errors that the map does not allow indexing, or the wrong type, or cant access the fields, etc...  How can you use a map and send it to a model and ensure that you have the most recent items listed first on the web page?

Comment: Are you trying to sort a map? Asking because maps in Go cannot be sorted. Or are you trying to store the contents of a map in a slice in a specific order?

Comment: Your first example collects the keys and sorts them. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: *How can you use a map and send it to a model and ensure that you have the most recent items listed first on the web page?* You cannot, not with a map. You can move the contents of a map into a slice and sort that slice using the `sort` package and pass the result to your model. Also see: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types *A map is an **unordered** group of elements of one type, ...* and https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action#TOC_7.

Comment: "_How can you use a map and send it to a model and ensure that you have the most recent items listed first on the web page?_"

The part 'most recent' makes me think that you could use a min-heap instead of a map. Take a look here to see how use a min-heap: https://golang.org/pkg/container/heap/.

Answer (score 2):

maps in go are always returned in a random order unless you use a key to access a value. so you can not reverse the order of a map because there is no order in the first place

Answer (score 0):

While you cant sort maps directly, you can wrap each key value pair in a new struct and sort this structarray. It just needs to implement the sort interface, like stated [here](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Sort)

Example:

```
type structSorter []mystruct
func (a structSorter) Len() int           { return len(a) }
func (a structSorter) Swap(i, j int)      { a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i] }
func (a structSorter) Less(i, j int) bool { return a[i].MyValue < a.[j].MyValue }
```

and called with

```
sort.Sort(structSorter(mystructArray))
```